# Cast column of type list[] to str in polars

Tags: python, python-polars, feature-engineering

Currently, using the polars' cast() method on columns of type list[] is not supported. It throws:

```
ComputeError: Cannot cast list type
```

Before I do as usual (use rows(), or convert to pandas, or work with apply()). Is there any trick or best practice to convert polars list[] to strings?

Here a quick snippet for you to replicate the error

```
df = pl.from_dict({'foo': [[1,2,3]], 'bar': 'Hello World'})
print(df)
'''
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬─────────────┐
│ foo       ┆ bar         │
│ ---       ┆ ---         │
│ list[i64] ┆ str         │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ Hello World │
└───────────┴─────────────┘
'''
df['foo'].cast(str)
# this other workaround wont work neither
df.select([pl.col('foo').str])
```

Here is what i expect to see:

```
'''
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬─────────────┐
│ foo       ┆ bar         │
│ ---       ┆ ---         │
│ str       ┆ str         │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╡
│"[1, 2, 3]"┆ Hello World │
└───────────┴─────────────┘
'''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the datatype `pl.List(pl.Utf8)`

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("foo").cast(pl.List(pl.Utf8)))
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌─────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ foo             | bar         │
│ ---             | ---         │
│ list[str]       | str         │
╞═════════════════╪═════════════╡
│ ["1", "2", "3"] | Hello World │
└─────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

To create an actual string - perhaps:

```
df.with_columns("[" + 
   pl.col("foo").cast(pl.List(pl.Utf8)).list.join(", ") 
   + "]"
)
```

or

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.format("[{}]",
      pl.col("foo").cast(pl.List(pl.Utf8)).list.join(", ")))
```

```
shape: (1, 3)
┌───────────┬─────────────┬───────────┐
│ foo       | bar         | literal   │
│ ---       | ---         | ---       │
│ list[i64] | str         | str       │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] | Hello World | [1, 2, 3] │
└───────────┴─────────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: tnx jquirious, I saw on other questions that you are a polars guru. However My goal is to convert the entire list to a string, basically the equivalent of str([1,2,3]) which can be achieved with apply, maybe you know another way to do that, check the answer again, i provided an output example

Comment: I'm more of a polars student. I've updated the answer with what I think is a way to do it without apply.

Comment: ```"[" + pl.col("FilialenNr.").cast(pl.List(pl.Utf8)).arr.join(", ") + "]"```. This works and it is a quite clever way to do it, and I am doing similar stuff actually. However it looks that pure cast of a list to str is not suppoerted yet. I will upvote and wait to accept, maybe somebody has the easy solution

Comment: This gives me an error: AttributeError: 'ExprArrayNameSpace' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: @DixieFlatline `.arr` has since been renamed to `.list`